# Spring unable to load resourcebundle

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle, properties-file

I have declared a component

```
@Component
public class I18nManagerImpl implements I18nManager{

@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle() {
    Locale fromConfig = Locale.UK;

    //Resolve Locale from a configuration service

    return new MessageSourceResourceBundle(messageSource, fromConfig); //replace code in my question
}
@Override
public String message(String locale) {
    ResourceBundle beanResourceBundle = getResourceBundle();
    String invalidEmail = beanResourceBundle.getString("invalidEmail");
    return invalidEmail;
}
```

}

And `messageSource` bean definition in `applicationContext.xml` is

```
<bean id="messageSource"         
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

But message cannot be found and if look with debugger ResourceBundle returned by getResourceBundle keys are null and there is no content.

What is wrong with the provided code?
Here is the image of project structure:[image]

Comment: Can you try with editing : <bean id="messageSource"         
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath*:messages/messages"/>
</bean>

Comment: Why are you using this? Why not simply use the default support available? What is so special that you need your own custom `I18nManagerImpl`

Comment: @Arpit not working, the same result.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you provide an example? I am going custom to add flexibility, enable caching and provide convenience methods to access certain translations not using raw string,

Comment: Your folder containing property file is "messages" or "Resource Bundle" or "Resource Bundle 'messages' "?

Comment: @Arpit it is just appearance. IntelliJ Idea does this to keep properties separated.  They are in folder resources.

Comment: The `MessageSource` already has caching and is by default already using the `MessageFormat`. More over you can use the `spring:message` tag to get the correct message, for errors/validation this is already provided/working out-of-the-box if you want to get a message yourself just use a plain `MessageSource`. To me it feels like you are working around things that already work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="messageSource"         
class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:messages"/>
</bean>
```

Add classpath

Also add-

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Since you are using annotation - Add

```
<annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="your.base.package" />
```

Namespace for resource -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: can you try with reloadableResourceBundle org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Comment: what is the namespace for resources?

Comment: That you can refer from here : https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/Spring-Social/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: And then try editing as : <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> <property name="basenames" value="classpath*:messages"/> </bean>

Comment: sorry, still the same.

Comment: Add the base package wherever you are using @Component using annotation

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. They are good, but unfortunately no result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that propoerties file was not in the source root. I inserted the file into src config folder and marked the folder as source root.